# Categorical variables in linear regression: one level with only one value, rest NA

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am coming with a theoretical question about how R works when running model summaries. I am doing some linear regression models where two of my variables are categorical, each with 3 levels, corresponding genotypes. I know that only two of the levels will show in the model summary, seeing as one of the levels has to be a reference. However, these variables of mine have only 1 count for one of the levels, as in:

Variable 1 levels: TT 176 counts /  TC 45 counts / CC 1 count (This out of 223 individuals genotyped).

Now, this CC level usually doesn't show up in the model summary, and I'm assuming it's because, since there is only 1, R isn't taking it into account. All I need then is to find a literature reference to confirm or deny my assumption. I've been trying to google this in different ways and going through the R `?help` for `lm` and other related searches, but either I haven't found what I'm looking for, or have and didn't understand it as such.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do these levels have a natural ordering? If not, I think the regression will overfit for the CC level in variable 1. There is only one observation to base that coefficient on, whereas regression is based on the idea of including "many" observations to say something about the average behavior

Comment: That's what I was thinking. But I need to be able to say with 100% certainty that this is indeed what's happening, that's why I'm looking for the literature source of this phenomenon (I'm preparing a thesis so I have to be ready with reliable sources to back my reasoning when explaining my results). First time ever working with R!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect.

The *first* level will be the reference level, and the default ordering is alphabetical. Because CC comes first alphabetically, it is the reference level in your model.

It is good practice (reduces variance of other estimates) to use a relatively common value as the reference level. Thus I would suggest modifying the alphabetical default to make `TT` the reference level. This should be as easy as

```
your_data$var = relevel(your_data$var, ref = "TT")
```

(of course substituting whatever your data frame and variable names are).

The way the levels are set is called the "contrasts". `?contrasts` is a good place to begin reading, and with that search term you should be able to find other docs/references as well. (There are options other than *"compare everything to the reference level"*, but that is out of the scope here.)

Similarly, it sounds suspect to include a level at all that has only a single observation, but that is a statistical question and not a programming one (and would require more information than is in your question), so I won't address it further here.

Comment: Hey @Gregor! I constantly change the reference level of these variables because I'm trying to analyze the estimates of the different genotypes), so I don't think that's the issue. CC will never appear in a model summary no matter what the reference is. I will definetely look into `?contrasts` now though, thanks for the tip. Any other suggestions? :) Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, with other variables, you have a singularity with CC. Does your modeling call produce warnings? Also, "constantly changing the reference levels" doesn't sound necessary, but again it doesn't sound on-topic here to discuss it. You might have better luck providing more detail on a new question at stats.stackexchange.

Comment: Hey! No warnings. About "constantly", I guess that's just a figure of speech, I'm moving the reference level around now that I'm trying to analyze how each genotype is affecting my dependent variable. Anyway, I'm thinking of removing the CC level altogether for the analysis, since it is reasonable to say that I can't draw any reliable conclusions from a single observation. I'll take a look at stats.stackexchange then. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe just leave out CC and fit a model with no intercept if your estimating effects independently rather than comparing them to each other.